# How to convert a text file date to useful SAS date format

Tags: date, datetime, sas, formatting

I currently received data in the form of a text file that has variables separated by | .
The current birth dates are listed as 12-OCT-23 format. Similarly, death dates are listed as 31-DEC-99. I'm trying to convert this into a proper SAS date format but encountering an issue every time.

```
data raw_Demographic;  infile "&path.\&demo." missover truncover dsd dlm = "|" ;
informat   birth_date anydtdte10.  death_dt        $10.  ;
format     birth_date mmddyy10.  death_dt        $10.  ;

input       birth_date  death_dt                     ;

if death_dt ne "0" then dte_death=input(death_dt, anydtdte10.);
    format  dte_death mmddyy10.;
    drop  death_dt;

if dte_death="31DEC1999"D then dte_death=.; *Note: this is because the format makes 9999 as 1999 so these are observations with no death date therefore we set to missing;
```

The problem is that this outputs dates as:

**Birth_date= 10/12/2023 but WANT 10/12/1923

Death_date=12/31/1999 but WANT 12/31/9999**

*Is there a way to convert this to the above format?*

Comment: I'm not sure of a "proper" way to do this due to the ambiguity of the original format but you can always just use `intnx` to shift the year. `new_date = intnx('year',birth_date,-100);`

Comment: Why would you want date in the year 9999? Even Mel Brooks' character was only 2000 years old.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Year_Old_Man

Comment: How to distinguish someone who has no died from someone who died on 2019-12-31?